# Git best practice when single file regularly changes?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `Jenkinsfile` file in multiple Git repositories, but different in each repository. This file is continuously updated, let's say once a month. The change in this file is completely unrelated to anything else in the repo, so every time the change is done in a separate Git branch.

How should such case be handled in Git branchwise? Should there be only one branch, reopened each time? What's the best practice?

Comment: i would reopen a branch for this

Comment: you say "*a* `Jenkinsfile` file in *multiple* Git repositories" ; are all those `Jenkinsfile` really verbatim copies of the same file ? or are there some modulations depending on the repository ?

Comment: @LeGEC They are different, dependent on repository.

Comment: I'll asume that your `Jenkinsfile` is used as a template, and you tweak it according to each repository... and when you update it _once a month_, it's because there's something common in all your repos that needs to be updated... Why don't you create a new repo (or reuse one) to use it as a common library? You can create some scripts that perform common actions in all your repos, and update only there when something changes...

Answer (score 0):

If it's the exactly same Jenkinsfile, you could use a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Another approach is to have a small, unmodified Jenkinsfile in the repository that is just a trigger to the real pipeline, which is stored in another repository. This way you could still be working with a multibranch repository and a SCM-stored Jenkinsfile elsewhere.

Comment: It's not the same file, it different in each repository.

Comment: You could use the same file, with the same content. This file would then load another file, named using the repo's name, for instance. All these secondary files - the real pipelines, let's call them that - would be stored in another repository.